# CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate

Tags: razor, blazor, visual-studio-2022

I am running VS2022 and got this error and the source of the file is from some file with the .g.cs extension.  The file is nowhere to be found, so this makes troubleshooting difficult.  Below is the screenshot:

[image: Error from the Visual Studio]

There is no additional error.

Comment: @Chris...my mistake...I need to learn how to use the Edit History feature.  With the attached screenshot, who can reopen the post?

Comment: Three Reopen votes must be cast. There is already one (yours, presumably?) and this post is in the Reopen queue. That's how I found it. Users will be evaluating whether it should be reopened or not. (Personally, I am refraining from voting as I am not familiar enough with the technology.) If this image is clear enough to folks who know about VS and Blazor, it is likely that the question will be reopened. But it can take some time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out in my situation.  I have some reference to the properties of a class that was misspelled and VS is not designed to tell you.

Here's the code snippet:

```
<RadzenDropDown
   @bind-Value ="@_filteredMaterialGrade"
   AllowClear  ="true"
   Data        ="@Presenter?.MaterialGrades">
```

The reference in Data is plural, but the actual property name is singular.